# Для чего значимую переменную делать Nullable reference типом

Tags: c#, null, nullable

int? MySave = null;

Получается данная переменная может принимать значения int и значение null.
Теперь переменная MySave какого типа стала integer или Nullable? Как переменная может быть двух типов?
А не проще ли сделать тогда просто тип bool?
Можно какие нибудь простые примеры где может пригодится данная реализация

Comment: `тип?` это `Nullable<тип>` - то есть конкретный тип, один, просто для удобства сделали синтаксический сахар в виде знака вопроса после типа. `null` - это данной переменной нет вовсе а не "значение null", просто `int` - это по сути `int MySave = default;`, то-есть, задается автоматически значение по умолчанию (для `int` это `0`). Ну вот теперь сами думайте, каким должна быть ваша переменная, если ей не задают значение, `null` или `0`, где-то подходит одно, а где-то другое.

Comment: например для совместимости с различной сериализацией: числовое поле в JSON может быть, может быть 0, а может вообще не быть.

Comment: Т. Е Nullable<int> это один целый тип, как допустим long int или lolg long, правильно понимаю?

Comment: `int?` это эквивалент `Nullable<int>`, который за вас создадут и проинициализируют. Сам `Nullable<>` - это структура, которая содержит в себе два свойства (`HasValue` и `Value`), которыми и оперируют потом внутренности вашего приложения после компиляции (например проверка по типу `MySave == null` превратится в условный  `MySave.HasValue`). Другими словами, `int?` это некая обертка над конкретным типом, которая позволяет вам задать `NULL`. Ну и да, там происходит boxing/unboxing. Нашел [статью с примерами](https://habr.com/ru/companies/pvs-studio/articles/525818/), думаю станет понятней.